Tools to read files of format "xRechnung"
Working abroad and hearing that Germany (and possibly several other European countries) are enforcing the use of electronic invoices from the beginning of the year 2025.
Details for Germany on Wikipedia (in German)
We need affordable tools for a small nonprofit in Germany (eingetragener Verein) to be able to open and manage such invoices, to be ready when they start arriving. There could be such invoices for any order (office supplies) or subscription (quarterly web-access-fees). This will also potentially affect our end-of-year tax-declarations: If any expense was made and if the invoice is in xRechnung-format then we will probably need to submit our concerned expenses in this format.
We mainly need a tool for MS Windows, preferably OpenSource or free (as in speech). A one-time purchase would also be acceptable, subscriptions for a software are not welcome.
If any user has got more details about the legal requirements for non-profits, please share links or details. Maybe there will be a grace-period for non-profits. But it is probably pointless to resist; better to get ready and be able to receive and read and check such xRechnung-invoices.
Today I have received advertising for one tool, for money. So the legal requirements are probably real, not a hoax. Before we go and purchase, I would like to see what else is out there. Here is one example for one real tool (we are not affiliated; we are just on the mailing-list of the retailer):
E-Rechnung Viewer
This question is not about the creation of such invoices. That is another subject, for a separate question.
Update:
User @Robert thinks that my question is somewhat removed from reality. That would be good news. If we never receive xRechnungen, then we have no problems reading them. Still @Robert gave my a helpful trailhead for a click-path to a solution and I will provide one short answer as a note to myself.

I don't think you will encounter many plain xRechnung files in reality. Most developers will make use of the hybrid format ZUGFeRD v2.2/v2.3 (PDF/A-3 document with integrated XRechnung invoice data). For reading/crating ZUGFerD documents see e.g. https://zugferd.org/materials/e-invoicing/1.0.0/index.html

Thank you @Robert you got me on a good track. Normally I do not like it, when I receive "your question is wrong" but in this case I am glad that we have not spent money yet on some tool. The tool I mentioned in my question would also open the zugferd files. But if those invoices are hybrid, with a human-readable part, we will be fine.

https://github.com/xSentry/xrechnungs-generator will let you create them. Not what OP wants, but adding this to possibly help others

OP is very open minded. Just the question would have become too vast. Seems there are not many questions here (so far) about xRechnung and zugferd, so we are seeding.

Could some veteran user with enough points please create suitable tags for xRechnung and zugferd? I cannot and I am a beginner to this subject.

There is a tool here to open or read xRechnung documents:
xrechnung-visualization
I have not yet personally tested this solution but it looks real. Is probably not an easy drag-and-drop solution but good enough for our needs, since we are advised that we will not encounter many xRechnungen in real life.
I am learning about this technology and more and better answers are muchly welcome.
